# Comparación de arrays de char

Tags: c++

```
void ordenar (escuela x[], int longitud){

int indice, iteracion;
escuela aux;

for (iteracion = 1; iteracion < longitud; iteracion++){
    for (indice = 0; indice < longitud - iteracion; indice++){
        if (x[indice].provincia > x[indice+1].provincia){
            aux = x[indice];
            x[indice] = x[indice+1];
            x[indice+1] = aux;
        }
    }
}

for (iteracion = 1; iteracion < longitud; iteracion++){
    for (indice = 0; indice < longitud - iteracion; indice++){
        while (x[indice].provincia == x[indice+1].provincia){
            if (x[indice].ciudad > x[indice+1].ciudad){
                aux = x[indice];
                x[indice] = x[indice+1];
                x[indice+1] = aux;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Buenas tardes, tengo una pregunta respecto a esta comparación, el `x.provincia` y `x.ciudad` son arrays de `char` dentro de un `struct`.

Mi problema es que al usar esta función, queda igual que siempre cuando la muestro por pantalla. Con strings me anda perfecto pero como debo guardarlo posteriormente en un archivo, no puedo usar strings. Use una función strcmp y también me anda perfecto, pero quisiera saber si hay otra forma de hacerlo sin llamar a una función ni hacer un for para cada caracter.

Saludos
Brian

Comment: ¿Por qué haces *if (x[indice].provincia > x[indice+1].provincia)*? son arrays de char y no tiene sentido.  Tampoco entiendo *pero como debo guardarlo posteriormente en un archivo, no puedo usar strings*, en un archivo se pueden guardar strings perfectamente.  Y esta afirmación no es correcta *ni hacer un for para cada caracter* no haces un *for* cada caracter si no por cada array de *x*

Comment: No puedes comparar arreglos de `char` mediante equidad `==`. Añade la definición de la clase `escuela`.

Answer (score 1):

> Mi problema es que al usar esta función, queda igual que siempre cuando la muestro por pantalla.

Los arrays de caracteres no son comparables usando los operadores habituales (`>`, `<`, `==`, `>=`, `<=`, `!=`) ya que al no ser objetos no soportan la sobrecarga de operadores. Lo que hacen estos operadores sobre los arrays de tipo `char` es comparar las direcciones de memoria de los punteros (no hay que olvidar que un array es, implícitamente, un puntero).

Si usas arrays de caracteres te toca usar las funciones heredadas de C para comparar cadenas:

```
if( strcmp(x[indice].provincia,x[indice+1].provincia) > 0 )
```

Aunque yo te aconsejaría usar `std::string` y entonces ya si podrás usar los operadores de comparación directamente.

> Con strings me anda perfecto pero como debo guardarlo posteriormente en un archivo, no puedo usar strings.

Déjame adivinar... para trabajar con ficheros estás usando `FILE*`. ¿cierto? Es lo que tiene intentar programar en C++ como si fuese C.

`FILE*` es una herencia de C y no dispone, como es lógico, de sobrecargas para trabajar con la clase `std::string`... sin embargo que no se pueda hacer un uso directo no implica que no puedan usarse:

```
std::string cadena = "Una prueba de escritura";

FILE* fichero = fopen("prueba.txt","w");
fwrite(fichero,"%s",cadena.c_str());
fclose(fichero);
```

Por supuesto, usando `ofstream` (clase propia de C++) el diseño queda más limpio:

```
std::string cadena = "Una prueba de escritura";

std::ofstream fichero;
fichero.open("prueba.txt", std::ofstream::out);
fichero << cadena << '\n';
fichero.close();
```